# Apache camel SFTP file upload consuming lot of heap memory

Tags: apache-camel, sftp

I am using apache camel to send file from local machine to sftp server. The file size i am trying with is 100MB , and i observed sudden CPU usage spike and lot of heap memory being consumed , can you help how can i improve the performance here.
IS file content being read into memory ? if yes how to avoid that
because i don't want to process anything in file, i am just using this library just to push to server.
This is how i configured my route:

```
from("file://tmp?delete=true&localWorkDirectory=/tmp&antInclude=*.csv&readLock=changed&readLockTimeout=70000&readLockCheckInterval=1000")
        .onException(Exception.class)
        .log("something went wrong")
        .end()

        .onCompletion()
        .log("file successfully delivered ${file:name}")
        .end()

        .log("processing file ${file:name}")
        .to("sftp://127.0.0.1:22/test/in?jschLoggingLevel=INFO&password=xxxxxx&useUserKnownHostsFile=false&username=test");
```

[jconsole output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gG7Nw.png)

Comment: Your route code seems OK. You’re not converting or transforming the file, so it should be a simple file move. But 150Mb heap and 4% CPU is not unusual for a Camel/Java application. Are you using Spring Boot? Are you working in a resource constrained environment?

Comment: yes i am using spring boot, and yes i am not converting/transforming file, so is there any better ways to do in this case

Answer (score 0):

Java is a garbage collected language, so if there is plenty of memory available, the garbage collector will not be too eager to clean up unused memory. The memory will only be freed when the garbage collector runs.

You can determine the lower bound of memory required by your application with the -Xmx java option, preferably getting it lower than the size of the file you are trying to send, if you want evidence that camel delivers the file via a stream, and does not load the entire file contents into memory at the same time.

Example:

```
java -Xmx100m -jar YourJarFile.jar
```